# Isekai manga: main character is reincarnated, being son of retired heroes

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is reborn into a baby and his parents are retired heroes. They take care of him without any common sense, and when he decides to go out into the world he is super overpowered. (Still a child)

On his journey he meets a group of soldiers fighting against flying valkyries and saves everyone without any difficulty.

I remember reading it about a year ago and there were few chapters.

Comment: Bolaxa, when you return, if this is the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235146/manga-about-a-child-of-the-two-strongest-people-in-the-world-granted-to-them-by (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *That Inferior Knight, Lv. 999*.

The description for the manga includes the quotes which address the main character not having common sense, being over powered, and fighting flying humanoids (angels instead of the valkyries mentioned in the question):

> "Hmm...I have no talent."... is what Yuan grew up in the mountains thinking. He's a normal kind-hearted boy, but of the unusual things about him, is that his parents are a sage and a master martial artist. In other words, the world's strongest. Since Yuan was told he was the weakest, he leaves home to make his dreams of becoming a knight come true.

> "Armies of Angels? You mean the harmful birds? I'll just remove them altogether!"

Answer (score 2):

I believe the one he is looking for is "[The Wise Man's Grandchild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Man%27s_Grandchild)"

MC is reincarnated into a baby, raised by retired heroes. Goes out into the world with no common sense.