# Manga about a child of the two strongest people in the world granted to them by a goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't remember the title of a manga I read. In the start, two old people considered the strongest in the world, are given a chance by a goddess to have a child by turning back their youth. Many years later, it shows the child has very hard training and the two old people are trying not to spoil him and turn him superior by telling him that whatever he could do, many others can too. (Even though he was now the strongest child).

He also doesn't know that his parents are superior and that their friend is the prince of hell. He later goes to the city to become strong (because he was taught that he was weak) and ended up defeating a army of angels for the knights at the city and he took the knight test too.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this?  About how old the series might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Isekai manga: main character is reincarnated, being son of retired heroes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234787/isekai-manga-main-character-is-reincarnated-being-son-of-retired-heroes), this may be *[That Inferior Knight, Lv. 999](https://mangadex.org/title/39036/that-inferior-knight-lv-999)*.

[image: Front cover of *That Inferior Knight, Lv. 999]

> The supposedly weakest boy who mastered martial arts and magic, the world shakes his misunderstanding!?
>
> "Hmm...I have no talent."... is what Yuan grew up in the mountains thinking. He's a normal kind-hearted boy, but of the unusual things about him, is that his parents are a sage and a master martial artist. In other words, the world's strongest. Since Yuan was told he was the weakest, he leaves home to make his dreams of becoming a knight come true.
>
> "Eh!? Is it really possible to be defeated with a mere finger-flick by an 8-year-old kid?"
>
> "You heard the hero was the weakest member? You'd have to be out of your mind to fight that!"
>
> "Armies of Angels? You mean the harmful birds? I'll just remove them altogether!"
>
> Now, the boy who sees dragons as just lizards you can eat regularly thinks (I am weak. I'll have to get even stronger or else I'll never become a noble knight), will he ever be free from his misconceptions!?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much I have been looking for this forever! :)